# How to fix 'animation-fill-mode: forwards' in slidein animation?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

The menu slides in but after it goes back to left -350px. I want the menu to stay at left: 0px so people can see it

I tried using animation-fill-mode: forwards but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I've also tried different ways of animating it, for example expanding the menu width from  0 to 350px but no matter what I do it won't stay at the last frame of the animation.

```
.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    left: -350px;

  }

  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  left: -350px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #81C784;
  border: 1px solid #004D40;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  z-index: 2;

}

.run-slidein {
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu--open {
  display: block;
}
```

```
const toggleMenu = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('menu--open');

}

const toggleMenuAnimation = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('run-slidein');
}



const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');



const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-button')


menuButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  toggleMenu();
})

menuButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  toggleMenuAnimation();
})
```

I expect the animation to stop at the last frame but it doesn't.